# JS: event assignation

Tags: javascript, function, events, onclick, onload

I'm still learning the basics of JavaScript, I'm learning about events right now and I ran into a doubt:

Why does the onclick function must be declared in assignation?

I have this code for a counter that goes up when you click a button:

```js
let button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.onclick=function add1(){
  let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  input1.value = parseInt(input1.value) + 1;
}
```

this code works correctly, however if I tried to refactor the code like this:

```js
function add1(){
  let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  input1.value = parseInt(input1.value) + 1;
}

let button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.onclick = add1();
```

it doesn't. the function executes itself only once on page load rather than onclick.

I wanted to know what's the difference here?

Comment: Remove the `()`, since that's the operator that invokes it. `button1.onclick = add1;`

Comment: well talk about quick solutions. Thanks

Comment: Common mistake. You're welcome.

Comment: @slappy can you please post it as answer? just in case someone falls into the same trap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, remove the `()` where you're doing the assignment, since that's the operator that invokes a function.

```
button1.onclick = add1; // No parentheses
```

Now you're performing an assignment of the function object to the `.onclick` property, so that the browser's internal event system can invoke the function when an appropriate event takes place.